# Azure DevOps restrict access only with in the organization

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I have a requirement of restricting access to Azure DevOps only inside the organization network. How does it possible to do? Can I restrict for a range of IP addresses or is there any other method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure DevOps is a cloud service, so you can't directly restrict it to your IP address range, however there are a couple of options:

1) Azure DevOps is authenticated through Azure Active Directory. You can use Azure AD's [conditional access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/conditional-access/) to prevent logins from certain geographies and address ranges. [See here for an example](http://www.rebeladmin.com/2018/08/step-step-guide-configure-location-based-conditional-access-policies/). This will stop any unauthorised attempts from other addresses or outside of your organization.

2) If you are more concerned about where your CI/CD pipelines are running, you can set up local agents to keep your build and releases on-prem.