# Restricted access to Azure Devops repo for my organization users

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory

We have recently moved our code on azure devops. We have created user accounts in azure AD and same users we added to Azure Devops so that they can access code.

Now we want restricted access to repo.

I checked this url:
[Azure DevOps restrict access only with in the organization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58115337/azure-devops-restrict-access-only-with-in-the-organization)

Do I need P1 or P2 Azure AD to enable restricted access to Azure DevOps?

If yes how do I check my Azure AD is P1 or P2 or what?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/set-git-tfvc-repository-permissions?view=azure-devops

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need azure ad P1 to use conditional access. you can check this by logging into azure ad, and it shows you on the Overview blade, [image]

Comment: This should not be the accepted answer, because the answer to the first question is 'No'.  This answers the second question, but the second question should have only been answered if the answer to the first question was 'yes', which it is not.

Comment: that depends on what he meant by restricted access. as per his thread in SO, I took it to mean he may want to limit access to the devops repo by IP address. eg, in case a user gave his credentials to someone in some other geography to look at the code for them or some other such scenario. Also given that he already added users in devops to view code, it would be ok at least for me to assume that he knows about specific repo / project permissions screens.

Comment: @alphaz18, will this approach prevent users cloning git repos using PAT outside the organizations network?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to restrict user access to all repos, you can set the user's Access level to `Stakeholder`. Stakeholder has no permission to access repository .The detailed information about access level, please refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/access-levels?view=azure-devops&viewFallbackFrom=vsts).

[image]

If you want to restrict user access to a specific repo ,  you need to set the **Read** permission of the user or user group to `Deny` in the Repositories of Project Settings.

[image]

Comment: IMO, Microsoft really confuses things with "Access Levels".  They really look like "Licensing Levels" to me.  Although it is true that you can remove access to ALL repos by making the user a Stakeholder Access Level (because they haven't paid for access to repos), I like your second answer better.