# Limit access to an azure dev-ops repository to specific IP addresses

Tags: azure, security, azure-devops, azure-active-directory

I want to limit an azure repository to some IP addresses, while other repositories will be open to different IP addresses. To do so, I tried:

1 – to find a setting in azure dev ops to limit access to a repo to IP addresses – I could not find such a setting.

2 – to create a new organization in azure dev ops, transfer the repo to that new organization, and find a setting in azure dev ops to limit access to an organization to IP addresses – I could not find such a setting.

3 – to use azure ad conditional access to limit access to azure dev-ops – it can be done to the entire azure dev-ops application, but not to a specific origination \ repo.

4 – to create another azure dev-ops application in our subscription – I could not find how to do it.

Any idea what I need to do?

Answer (score 1):

> Limit access to an azure dev-ops repository to specific IP addresses

As we know the Azure devops services is a cloud service, so we could directly restrict it to your IP address range with Azure devops settings.

To resolve this request, you could create your Azure DevOps Server and set up a firewall on the server machine, so that only some specified IP address can access the Azure devops server.

Besides, if you do not want to set your Azure DevOps Server, you could also try to use Azure AD's [conditional access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/conditional-access/) to prevent logins from certain geographies and address ranges.

You could check this guide [Learn about Active Directory and Various Azure Services](https://www.rebeladmin.com/2018/08/step-step-guide-configure-location-based-conditional-access-policies/) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61847970/restricted-access-to-azure-devops-repo-for-my-organization-users) for some more details.

Comment: Thank you!
Conditional access seems like the right solution. However, in the conditional access I can select the Azure DevOps as a service and not a specific repository or specific organization.
Can I create another Azure DevOps service on the same subscription with the same Azure AD?

Comment: @Omri, You can create another **organization** on the same subscription with the same Azure AD

Comment: unfortunately Azure AD conditional access does not support selecting a specific organization :\