# Need to limit access to Git Repository by allowing only MAC address or any other possible way

Tags: git, azure-devops, repo

Anyone who has access to Git repos can download codes from anywhere, not from a particular PC. I need to allow them to have access only from one PC by restricting from their MAC address or any other possible way. I cannot use their static IP since they are not under any internal network neither they have static public IPs.

Comment: MAC addresses are not useful as soon as you are in different networks. This XY problem will get you nowhere.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/61847970/1462295 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/58115337/1462295